# How can I draw from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MainForm class. Here I can make somthing like this.

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 100, 150, 150);
    graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rectangle);
    graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rectangle);
}
```

And I can see result in my Form.

But I have another **class Image**. And I want to draw from here. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you mean you already  have an instance of a `System.Drawing.Image` and you want to draw it instead of the rectangles and ellipses?

Comment: Image is my own class, where I want to put some methods to draw figures in MainForm.

Comment: you can pass the graphic object to you class and handle the drawing process within the class method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the PaintEventArgs (the below came from one i have been using)

```
class Draw
{
    public void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
          e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Blue, GetRectangle());                        
    }
}
```

where GetRectangle would be another method to define the rectangle

you should also be able to just send your object (in your case the instance of MainForm)

```
class Draw
{
    public void Paint(MainForm main)
    {
        Graphics graphics = main.CreateGraphics();
    }
}
```

or the graphics object

```
class Draw
{
    public void Paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 100, 150, 150);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, rectangle);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rectangle);
    }
}
```

you still need the event handler for the PictureBox, so you would do something like

```
private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Draw image = new Draw();
    image.Paint(graphics);
}
```

Comment: if I'll use the last one variant, what should I write inside of **private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) { ... }**?

Comment: fixed answer with example

Comment: Ok, it works. And what should I change to display my paintings inside of PictureBox?

Comment: send the PictureBox to the Draw class.  personally, if i was doing multiple operations on the PictureBox, i would probably use it in the class constructor for Draw rather than sending it into a bunch of methods

Comment: You shouldn't use `CreateGraphics` apart from when you do temporary drawings (for instance a selection rectangle), otherwise the `Paint` event and its `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` object is what you should draw with. But if you use `CreateGraphics` _**you must**_ dispose the `Graphics` object when you're done or else you'll get memory leaks.

Comment: @VisualVincent I would never use it myself, but that is a useful comment for the discussion and future.  thanks

Comment: I'm writing **Graphics graphics = PictureBox.CreateGraphics();** instead of **Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();** and it doesnt work. How can I do it correctly to make it work?

Comment: You should never call `CreateGraphics` on a picturebox. If you are trying to do custom drawing you should just use a simple `Panel` object instead. Picture Boxes are inteded to be used with the `System.Drawing.Image` and not for custom drawing. Also, when working with controls you should rarely call `CreateGrapics()` you need to do your drawing inside of the `Paint` event and use `e.Graphics` instead.